# How does this fuel pump work?

Tags: turboprop, fuel-systems

This question is about the fuel pump controlled by the hydro-mechanical fuel control unit.

- This is part of a fuel system for a turboprop engine, described [on this page](http://aeromodelbasic.blogspot.fr/2012/01/fuel-control-system.html) which actually comes from a Rolls-Royce book. [Full picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB2IE.jpg) for convenience.

I've been staring in vain at this picture for some time, with the hope that something will suddenly become clear:

[image]
<sup>[Source](http://aeromodelbasic.blogspot.fr/2012/01/fuel-control-system.html)</sup>

The pump is supposed to receive low pressure fuel and deliver high pressure fuel at a rate modulated by the FCU using fuel in the purple pipe. The engine speed governor also modulates the pump output.

- It seems to be a piston pump, pistons being moved in translation by the rotating plate on the left side, but I'm not even sure, and I don't understand how this increases pressure.
- It seems the governor is not rotating... and I don't get the role of the green governor pressure fuel.

Can you help me understanding how it works?
(I've posted all the details I could gather as an "answer").

Comment: Does the [description on the "Read More" link offer the info you are looking for](http://aeromodelbasic.blogspot.fr/2012/01/fuel-control-system.html#more)?

Comment: @RonBeyer: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes diagrams can be mystifying. This is a video of a variable displacement hydraulic pump of similar principle being torn apart (disassembled would be too gentle a term) by a foul-mouthed Canadian who gives an excellent detailed & clear description of its construction & operation. Language warning for those not used to frontier engineering.

Which will prepare you for this very polite Canadian who shows an actual aircraft fuel pump. (around 7:30)